# rename named export without export default

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I do have an issue when I want to decorate my export with a wrapper.
I have a wrapper/hof function that encapsulate the real function like this:

```
import { withSth } from './anotherFile'
import { someConst } from './someConst'

const myFunc = () => {}
export {
  myFunc: withSth(someConst, myFunc)
}
```

> Parsing error: ',' expected.

This does not work while this work:

```
import { withSth } from './anotherFile'
import { someConst } from './someConst'

const myFunc = () => {}
module.exports = {
  myFunc: withSth(someConst, myFunc)
}
```

The only way i can do this is like this:

```
import { withSth } from './anotherFile'
import { someConst } from './someConst'

const myFuncX = () => {}
const myFunc = withSth(someConst, myFuncX)
// OR 
// const myFync = withSth(someConst, () => {})
// but it lose readability
module.exports = {
  myFunc
}
```

My point is how can I do the same thing with export and without using default export and renaming all my function

```
module.exports = {
  methodA: withSth(param, methodA),
  methodB: withSth(param, methodB),
  methodC: withSth(param, methodC),
  methodD: withSth(param, methodD),
}
```

Comment: You cannot have a local variable and an export with the same name but different values. Rename one of them.

Comment: i read it so many times and I still don't understand what you want to do.

Comment: still the same @FelixKling if you try to export { someName: 'toto' } it will not work :/

Comment: export { } is not a valid syntax for commonjs - please read https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_exports

Comment: it is valid you can export { namedFunc, namedConst, ... } https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export see Export list

Comment: Es6 export is valid, commonjs is module.exports

Comment: @FelixKling Technically you can do `const a=0, b=1; export { b as a }` but I wouldn't recommend it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike Commonjs modules (with `module.exports`), ES6 modules do not export *values* but *variable bindings*. You must declare a variable<sup>1</sup>, you cannot export something unnamed. So your choices are only

```
export const myFunc = withSth(someConst, myFuncX);
```

```
const myFuncX = () => {};
export const myFync = withSth(someConst, () => {});
```

```
const myFuncX = () => {};
const myFyncY = withSth(someConst, () => {});
export { myFuncY as myFunc }
```

<sub>1: with the exception of `export default …;`, which implicitly declares a variable with an unforgeable name for you. But you want multiple named exports.</sub>